# Ошибка angular Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Вот конф. приложения, подключаю reslove к контролеру Main

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl:'html/main.html',
      controller:'Main',
      resolve:{
          data:function () {
              return 'data';
          }
      }
    })
}])
```

Здесь вот пробую выводить данные

```
app.controller('Main', function ($scope, data) {
         $scope.title = 'Main Controller';
         console.log(data);
});
```

В консоль данные вывелись но появляется [ошибка](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=dataProvider%20%3C-)

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос? По вашей ссылке есть вся необходимая информация об ошибке. Скорее всего, ошибка возникает при минификации кода, попробуйте в контроллере `app.controller('Main',['$scope', 'data', function ($scope, data) {}]);`

Comment: добавьте html разметку, а также разметку для шаблона и полный текст ошибки из консоли, в идеале - пример на plunkr воспроизводящий ошибку

Comment: @OlgaAkhmetova, проблема скорее всего не в минификации, так как по ссылке на ошибку видно что не найден dataProvider, то есть не минифицированное название, скорее всего в нескольких местах прописано использование контроллера `Main` и если по роуту ему data - подставляется, то в другом месте - нет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [AngularJS - ошибка Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- testCtrl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/965276/angularjs-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-unknown-provider-eprovider-e-testctrl)