# AngularJS - ошибка Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- testCtrl

Tags: angularjs

Коллеги, в ***AngularJS***, я абсолютный новичок. Это мой первый пример.

Чтобы не приводить все, что у меня есть  [ссылка на репозиторий](https://github.com/sarnor/club), можно клонировать и запустить.

> Чтобы запустить ***development*** команда **npm run dev**
>
> ---
>
> Чтобы запустить ***production*** команда **npm run build** 
>   и отдельно сервер **npm start**
>
> (надо установить ***nodemon*** не указан в зависимостях)

А теперь о проблеме с которой я столкнулся.

Есть такой короткий примитивный пример

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Sarnor_Club</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div id="root">
        <img src="${require(`../image/icons/up.png`)}" width="50" height="50" alt="" />
        <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

---

```
let ngModule = angular.module('app', []);

let slovo = 'slovo';

ngModule.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = slovo;
})
```

Если запускаю в режиме ***development*** то все работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если запустить в режиме ***production***, то вот такая картина

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По ссылке в консоли с ошибкой отправляет [сюда](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/docs/error/$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e%20%3C-%20testCtrl)

Помогите разобраться, что это за ошибка ***Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- testCtrl*** и почему ***production*** пример не работает?

Comment: а если код изменить следующим образом: `ngModule.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope',  function($scope) {
  $scope.message = slovo;
}])`

Comment: Работает. Опиши ответом, в чем разница и почему так... Благодарю...

Comment: ответом не смогу, поэтому дам тут общее пояснение, может придет @Grundy и даст хороший ответ(в свое время сталкивался с этой же проблемой и он помог), смысл заключается в том что при режиме production, код [минифицируется](http://devacademy.ru/posts/uglublyaemsya-vo-vnedrenie-zavisimostej-v-angularjs/) и в следствии этого вылезают вот такие ошибки

Comment: Будем ждать...)))))) @Grundy

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30127409/2881286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При минификации код

```
.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
```

преобразуется во что-то вроде:

```
.controller('testCtrl', function(e) {
```

И так как провайдер `eProvider` нигде не описан получается указанная ошибка.

---

Данное поведение описано в [справке](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#injection-function-annotation), там же даны и способы решения:

1. [аннотация `$inject`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#-inject-annotation)

   ```
   function testCtrl($scope) {
       $scope.message = slovo;
   }
   testCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
   ngModule.controller('testCtrl', testCtrl);
   ```
2. [`inline` аннотация](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#inline) - в этом случае параметром передается массив, в котором сначала идет перечисление зависимостей:

   ```
   ngModule.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.message = slovo;
   }])
   ```

<sub>Перевод ответа [@Grundy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30127507/2881286)</sub>

Comment: Grundy, ты как всегда..))  Благодарю...